# How to prove the claim that the wave packet is normalized

Tags: quantum-mechanics

As we know, the wave function representing a plane wave, is not normalized. The plane wave equation is of the form (in general):

$\psi(\vec r,t)=\psi_0e^{i( \vec k \vec r - \omega t)}$

Calculating:

$|\psi(\vec r,t)|=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(\vec r,t)^*\psi(\vec r,t)d\vec r$.

$|\psi(\vec r,t)|=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi_0|^2\vec r$.

$|\psi(\vec r,t)|=|\psi_0|^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vec r$. This goes to infinity. I am not sure whether my derivation is correct, so I'd like a confirmation.

A wave packet can be written as (this is how we wrote it in our lecture):

$\psi(\vec r,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^3}}\int g(\vec k)e^{i( \vec k \vec r - \omega t)}d^3k$

where $g(\vec k)$ is the fourier Transform of $\psi(\vec r,t=0)$.

How can I prove that the wave packet is normalized, given in a general expression. Unless that's not possible and we need to specify how the wave packet equation looks like

Comment: You have to specify what the wave-packet looks like.  $\psi(\vec{r},t)$ will be normalized (i.e., square integrable) if and only if $g(\vec{k})$ is, because the Fourier transform is a unitary transformation on the space of square-integrable functions.

Comment: two questions: 1) Is my proof that the plane wave is not normalized correct? 2) What do you mean with : " because the Fourier transform is a unitary transformation on the space of square-integrable functions." If one was to ask you, why you claim or assume that the wave packet is normalized, how would you give an intuitive explanation ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's compute :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int |\psi(\vec{r},t)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}^3\vec{r} 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \int\mathrm{d}^3\vec{k}_1 \int\mathrm{d}^3\vec{k}_2 \int\frac{\mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}}{(2\pi)^3} \,g(\vec{k}_1,t)g(\vec{k}_2,t)^*e^{i(\vec{k}_1-\vec{k}_2)\cdot\vec{r}} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \int\mathrm{d}^3\vec{k}_1 \int\mathrm{d}^3\vec{k}_2 \,g(\vec{k}_1,t)g(\vec{k}_2,t)^*\delta^{(3)}(\vec{k}_1-\vec{k}_2) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \int |g(\vec{k},t)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}^3\vec{k} \\
\end{array}
$$
From this relation, we deduce that $\psi(\vec{r},t)$ is normalizable (that is square-integrable) if and only if $g(\vec{k},t)$ is also square-integrable, i.e. $\psi \in L^2 \Leftrightarrow g \in L^2$, since $\|\psi\|_2 = \|g\|_2$, which is nothing else than Plancherel theorem stating that the Fourier transform is unitary over $L^2$.

---

**N.B. :** I used a plane wave expansion with respect to the spatial coordinates only, but you can adapt the derivation by taking $g(\vec{k},t) = \displaystyle\int g(\vec{k},\omega)\,e^{-i\omega t} \,\mathrm{d}\omega$ in order to convert time into the frequency domain.